# How to convert bash array to list and save to a file?

Tags: bash

I'm having array and I want to convert it in the form of list and save it to a file.

Here is what I tried:

```
export arrVal=(a,b,c)
echo NEWLIST="${arrVal[@]}" >> newtextfile
```

Output:

```
NEWLIST=a,b,c
```

Expected Output:

```
NEWLIST=[a,b,c]
```

Comment: `arrVal=(a,b,c)` creates an array with **one** element. It's value is `a,b,c`. Separate with spaces to create more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the square brackets to your expression, something like that:

```
export arrVal=(a,b,c)    
echo NEWLIST="[${arrVal[@]}]"
```

Output:

```
NEWLIST=[a,b,c]
```

Comment: thans for the answer what happens if I remove **export** keyword?

Comment: With export variable is a environment variable, without is a "shell" variable. If you need to use same variable in other part (for example to define a path in a configuration of a software) you need to keep export keyword.

Comment: I want to use NEWLIST as a list in **.env** file so I asked

Comment: You can avoid export keyword.

Comment: Currently I'm having one array and integer variable in bash how to write to a file at once without appending? here I should write to newtextfile. Can you please help me with this one. Thank you **Jacopo Bonomi**

Comment: You can create a variable with formatted text, and write on file only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As @pmf wrotes in comment...

```
arrVal=(a,b,c)
```

...is only one value of key `0`.

Look...

```
array=(a,b,c)
echo ${#array[@]} # puts out: 1
# Or only key 0...
echo ${array[0]} # puts out: a,b,c
```

Now...

```
array=(a b c)
echo ${#array[@]} # puts out: 3

# You can loop over it with...
for key in ${array[@]}; do echo ${key}; done
# That puts out...
a
b
c
```